# Device HPET in DSDT patch returns error while compiling "object is not accessible from this scope (BUF0)"

Tags: macos, patch, acpi, dsdt, hpet

Does anyone know how to get rid of this compiling error? This is device in the dsdt, I am using a patch from a repository.

The original device HPET is:

```
Device (HPET)
                {
                    Name (_HID, EisaId ("PNP0103"))  // _HID: Hardware ID
                    Name (ATT3, ResourceTemplate ()
                    {
                        IRQNoFlags ()
                            {0}
                        IRQNoFlags ()
                            {8}
                        Memory32Fixed (ReadWrite,
                            0xFED00000,         // Address Base
                            0x00000400,         // Address Length
                            )
                    })
                    Name (ATT4, Buffer (0x02)
                    {
                         0x79, 0x00                                     
                    })
                    Method (_STA, 0, NotSerialized)  // _STA: Status
                    {
                        If (LEqual (OSFX, 0x03))
                        {
                            If (HPTF)
                            {
                                Return (0x0F)
                            }
                            Else
                            {
                                Return (0x00)
                            }
                        }
                        Else
                        {
                            Return (0x00)
                        }
                    }
```

The patched one, It's throwing that error. The problem is like this I am trying to boot OSX but I get a No hpet error.

```
Device (HPET)
                    {
                        Name (_HID, EisaId ("PNP0103"))  // _HID: Hardware ID
                        Name (ATT3, ResourceTemplate()
                        {
                            IRQNoFlags() { 0, 8, 11, 15 }



                            Memory32Fixed (ReadWrite,
                                0xFED00000,         // Address Base
                                0x00000400,         // Address Length
                                )
                        })
                        Name (ATT4, Buffer (0x02)
                        {
                             0x79, 0x00                                     
                        })




                        Name (_STA, 0x0F)
                        Method (_CRS, 0, NotSerialized)
                        {
                            Return (BUF0)
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: And why 11 and 15 in the list?

Comment: I think it’s result of a rehabman patch

Comment: I would recommend to remove those entries from the list.